# SQL select total number of chats from messages

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I select the total number of chats from the messages table.
For example in my table I have these cols:
id (Auto Ic Primary Ky) / sender / recipient / message / time / date
As they will of course be multiple messages between users, such as maybe 6 rows, where the sender 7 and the recipient is say 8, I need each duplicate result like this to be limited to one.
Current sql code:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE sender = $u_id OR recipient = $u_id
```

Comment: The reference to auto increment (sort of) suggests that you are really using MySQL.  I fixed the tags.  You should edit the question and provide . .. well a question.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: So, you actually want all the distinct pairs of users (senders/recipients)?

Comment: What if there are two rows, `sender=7, recepient=8` and `sender=8, recepient=7`, should they count as one or two?

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, if duplicates such as that, they would count as "one chat" because those are messages between only two users.
What I'm looking for to be outputted, is simply the recipients id rather than my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should handle these situations by pulling a set of unique sender/recipient combinations, then counting them.  Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as TotalChats
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Sender, Recipient
      FROM Messages
      WHERE Sender = $u_id OR Recipient = $u_id) as M
```

Edit:... Based on comments, you actually want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Recipient
FROM Messages
WHERE Sender = $u_id
```

But you should add sample data and expected results to you question - it will be a lot more clear that way.